# How to change TextBlock.Text every loop?

Tags: c#, uwp

This is UWP C# application. I want to display the **i** variable.

```
    private void btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<=10000000; i++)
        {
            textBlock2.Text = i.ToString();
        }
    }
```

But after I clicked the button, the text only change one time after the loop is finished.

How can see changing text in every loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, your UI is frozen while the long loop is executing, so nothing can be updated on the screen. Try this

```
private async void btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<=10000000; i++)
    {
        textBlock2.Text = i.ToString();
        await Task.Delay(200); //stay 200 ms before showing next number so human eyes can see it.
    }
}
```

When it executes to this line `await Task.Delay(200);`, the loop is temporarily suspended - for 200 milliseconds, and the UI thread now has a chance to process the drawing tasks pending in the queue, which includes redrawing the textblock.

Comment: Better to use `BackgroundWorker` here, let the UI thread do its work and background thread do its work. Mixing between logic is not a good practice.

Comment: BackgroundWorker was an invention in WinForms era...I think we don't use it anymore.

Comment: 10000000 * 200 ms ~ 23 days. This will be a long for-loop:)

Comment: @kennyzx: BackgroundWorker is in System.ComponentModel and resides in System.dll. Can be used basically anywhere, regardless of actual technology (and supports reporting progress). But since async-await exists its relevance declined greatly.

Comment: I have just learned that it is still in .NET Core and .NET standard, pretty surprised. It was “invented” - as I called - to hide multi-threading from developers, just put you code inside the DoWork method like Btn_Click, and maybe it is kept to make the life easier for those who need to maintain old codebase.

Comment: @kennyzx It's absolutely still used today, it wasn't "invented" to hide anything, it's there to manage background threads for you and let you schedule code on them to reuse threads instead of creating your own wastefully. It's used by the TPL internally so it's not going anywhere anytime soon, when you use Tasks you're often using the background worker internally, it has absolutely nothing to do with winforms.

Comment: @RonanThibaudau, is there any docs, which says that `TPL` is using `BackgroundWorker` internally? All I have found is telling, that `TPL` is "next generation" of `BackgroundWorker`, but this doesn't mean that it uses `BackgroundWorker` internally.

Comment: @vasily.sib Leaving my comment instead of deleting it so the conversation makes sense but i totally mixed things up and was of course thinking of the ThreadPool when i typed this, so ignore my first comment.